# Can't focus on textarea after change event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Not sure why this doesn't work in Firefox (works fine in Chrome). Basically trying to focus on the current textarea with id "test" after making a change to the text.

```
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<textarea id="test2"></textarea>
```

And JQuery code:

```
$('#test').change(function() {
    alert("You entered: "+$(this).val());
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Refer to: http://jsfiddle.net/e0fahvh0/

This is not a duplicate, as the questions asked before (refer to [Calling $().focus on a textarea in Firefox doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278178/calling-focus-on-a-textarea-in-firefox-doesnt-work-as-expected)) was via a click event, this is a change event and it's somehow different!

Comment: By the way use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).text()`

Comment: Thanks @Dan you're right LOL, I only quickly put this together for debugging purpose :P I've updated it to .val()

Comment: This might provide an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278178/calling-focus-on-a-textarea-in-firefox-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: @Mahan did you try it in Firefox?

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I saw that one before posting mine, if you try that in JSFiddle, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @guowy I tried it on firefox, I replicated your problem. please try my answer below and tell if that's the behaviour you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we just need to **create a delay** to give the focus on the textarea

```
$('#test').change(function() {
    var ttt = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
         alert("You entered: "+ttt.val());
         ttt.focus();
    },50);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dL442hjo/1/

Comment: Thanks, but did you test your answer in JSFiddle? The alert prompt kept coming up, that's not the effect I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: yeah, what are you trying to achieve here? do you want to have the alert after all the changes was made? are you trying to make a character counter?

Comment: I have an edited my fiddle

Comment: Thanks, using the setTimeout seems to be able to hack it through Firefox :) Not ideal, but it does resolve this matter. Thanks :)